# Перенос программы, написанной на python на docker (ubuntu)

Tags: python, docker

Здравствуйте я совсем недвано начал изучать Docker и у меня возникла проблема. Есть программа она довольно большая. Из [https://hub.docker.com/_/python/](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) я узнал общую структуру запуска файлов в python

FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/parsers/parsers

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]

Я чуть переделал его и docker build отработал хорошо, но при этом в файле, который я хочу запустить используется класс, который был описан в другом файле т.е.

```
from parsers.common.rabbit import *
from parsers.common.constants import *
```

и при запуске docker run у меня выбивает ошибку потому что он не видит папки parsers.common...
Как нужно добавить туда папку parsers, чтобы он наконец увидел эти функции (P.S. знаю, что вопрос, наверное, очевидный, но найти в google я его не смог поэтому если вы нашли ответ на этот вопрос буду благодарен за ссылку)

Answer (score 0):

> WORKDIR /usr/src/app/parsers/parsers

Можно **упростить** `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`.

Иначе абсолютный путь для `parsers` - `/usr/src/app/parsers/parsers/parsers`.

> COPY . .

**Проверить** `.dockerignore`, что папки реально попали в docker образ.

```
docker run --rm -it image bash # (or on alpine sh)
```

Таким образом получаем `shell` можно дебажить. 
Очень помогает на этапе написания / тестирования образа.

> from parsers.common.rabbit import *

Проверить **наличие** `__init__.py` в папках модулей, возможно не попадают в образ.

**Примеры использования** `.dockerignore`:

```
*
!*.py
!core/*.py
!*.txt
!wait-for
!*.ini
!alembic/*
__pycache__
```

Использую тактику *белых списков*. Сначала запрещаю все, а затем c `!` разрешаю нужное. Можно использовать, когда проект мал или очень много файлов, которые не будут использоваться в работе.

Или обычные *черные списки*

```
*.env
*.md
*.yml
```